# Action of $A_n$ on cosets by translation

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

This exercise is from Lang's *Algebra*.

> Let $n\geq 3$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of the alternating group $A_n$. Suppose that $H$ has index $n$ in $A_n$. Show that the action of $A_n$ on $A_n/H$ by translation induces an isomorphism between $A_n$ and the alternating group $Alt(A_n/H)$ on $A_n/H$.

The action by left-translation gives a group homomorphism $\phi$ from $A_n$ to $Sym(A_n/H)$. If we can prove that every member of $Alt(A_n/H)$ is in the image of $\phi$, then we immediately obtain that $\phi$ is an isomorphism: if the image of $\phi$ contains $Alt(A_n/H)$ then it is exactly $Alt(A_n/H)$ by cardinality and then $\phi$ is injective, being a surjective map between two sets of the same cardinality. I don't manage to prove this fact, though. I have tried considering the cycle structure of an arbitrary element $\sigma\in Alt(A_n/H)$ but couldn't find an element $a\in A_n$ such that $\sigma$ is left-translation by $a$.

Comment: Do you know the result that $A_n$ is simple when $n \ge 5$?

Comment: I do. I see that one can use this to prove that $\phi$ is injective, but how to show that the image only consists of even permutations?

Comment: Otherwise the intersection of the image with the alternating group would have index two in the alternating group, contradicting its simplicity. By the way, you still need to do the cases $n=3$ and $n=4$, but they are not hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n\geq 3$ and $n\neq 4$, $A_n$ is simple. The kernel of $\phi$ is included in $H<A_n$, so that by simplicity $\ker(\phi)=\{e\}$. If $g\in im(\phi)$, then $g^2\in im(\phi)\cap Alt(A_n/H)$ since the sign of a square is $1$. It follows that $|im(\phi)\cap Alt(A_n/H)|\geq \frac1{2}|im(\phi)|$. Rearranging and using the fact that $|A_n|=|Alt(A_n/H)|$, we obtain $[Alt(A_n/H) : im(\phi)\cap Alt(A_n/H)]\leq 2$. The index cannot be two, for a subgroup of index $2$ is normal and $Alt(A_n/H)$ is simple. Thus the index is one and $im(\phi)=Alt(A_n/H)$.

It remains to treat the case $n=4$. In this case $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $3$ of $A_4$, and the order of $\ker(\phi)$ is $1$ or $3$. $A_4$ does not have a normal subgroup of order $3$ (there are $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups and all of them are conjugated). Thus $\phi$ is injective. Finally $|Alt(A_4/H)\cap im(\phi)|\geq 6$ but $A_4$ does not have a subgroup of order $6$ (this subgroup would be abelian, thus having a normal subgroup of order $3$ but none exists in $A_4$), so that $im(\phi)$ is again $Alt(A_4/H)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Derek Holt's comment plus the fact that intersection of two normal subgroups is normal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can prove that $\phi$ is injective using this. I still can't figure out why $im(\phi)\subseteq Alt(A_n/H)$ though.

Comment: Aah, I see. Every element is a product of transpositions, so it suffices to look at $\phi(g)$ for $g$ a transposition. I see that $\phi(g)$ is itself a transposition, so that the image of a product of an even number of transpositions is going to be an even number of transpositions, so an even permutation. Is that right?